# LibUSB uninitialized constant USB (NameError)

Tags: ruby, usb, libusb

I tried to run some code with libusb:

```
require 'libusb'
USB::devices.each { |d| puts "device (#{d.product_name}) vendor: #{d.vendor_id} product: #{d.product_id}" }
```

But when i run it:

```
C:\icd_programm>ruby libusb.rb
libusb.rb:2:in `<main>': uninitialized constant USB (NameError)
```

Why do i get such an error? I followed this instructions:http://www.technofetish.net/mike/demo1.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that there is no class or module named `USB`. The instructions you referred to seem to use an older version of `libusb` that originally defined the `USB` module.

Here's how to do it in newer versions of `libusb`:

```
require 'libusb'

usb = LIBUSB::Context.new
usb.devices.each{ ... }
```

Source: https://github.com/larskanis/libusb

Comment: Right answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you can help me, with my new issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401686/libusb-undefined-method-all-input-usages

Comment: hey, did you know how to send and fetch file from usb in ruby ?

Comment: @puneet18 sorry, i have little to no experience writing software that interacts with usb. This was just a Ruby question, nothing usb specific per se.