# Undefined method all_input_usages using libusb

Tags: ruby, usb, libusb

I wrote this little demo code with [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb):

```
require 'libusb'

usb = LIBUSB::Context.new
device = usb.devices(:idVendor => 2362).first
puts device.all_input_usages
```

But somehow I don't get the error:

```
 undefined method `all_input_usages' for #<LIBUSB::Device:0x2091fa8>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that code? That method simply doesn't exist.

Comment: You can see all available methods in IRB when you type `device.methods - Object.new.methods`, it's a trick i often use when i want to explore what an object has to offer. Maybe this will help you find the method you are looking for.

Comment: Demo code, from an lecture: http://www.technofetish.net/mike/demo2.txt    Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i90PfkapMtc

Comment: You should step away from that demo code, because it is hopelessly outdated and the API has radically changed since.

Comment: Can you write your comment as an question? So that i can rate it? Thanks! And where would you recommend me to look for avaible methods in libusb?

Comment: And  i have an new question, but maybe i will delete it! What would you say? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402481/libusb-how-to-get-avaible-device-commands Or you can answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should step away from that demo code, because it is hopelessly outdated and the API has radically changed since.

You can see all available methods in IRB when you type `device.methods - Object.new.methods`, it's a trick i often use when i want to explore what an object has to offer. Maybe this will help you find the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the idVendor should be written in hexadecimal spelling, so maybe `device = usb.devices(:idVendor => 0x2362).first` will work.